# How to show selection / calculated data in vega-lite tooltip?

Tags: vega-lite

I'm trying to calculate price difference of a selection in a chart provided in [Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXCAxgewHYwIYQwUwCcQAaEKbHJUAN2wBsBXfAZyQG1QKZ8kQAmAAz8AjAFpBAFgkBWACqDBiRaRAAHQhBS9EIgGwBmAHSSZAXxJdKOgcPFSJehUpVkNWnfpFGA7Ocvk1nxCohLSgj7OyoKq7tpIIjIAnCb8FlY8wXZhEgAcUa7qmvG6evxG-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-DsSA+a8coZBxoQS4ZlgfCkQQ7bTjAaBqEBGFoKmqYsPgzZCRRTF8GAcBNrw3TKap6l8Yx1HILR9HhqeARYbhyBqGgeDNmQUYxvGibydgKBNuewEURgsZVpgiZ0EwOj3LkO6idWfC9h+xCudWagFkgqYMGpEZhcwx5IbZ7b2SAcEyXmokYCwoEdhwIEQPQPDMeo7bYLFyCxipIA2aAkCBWgYDVSA8l8OmA4wAA+tln4gOmmbZg5oxkNgQFTRAI2jRChlqJJi1jRNqjTVec3LAtS0oSwY3reGASzvQKCMChALcLBRinedrQAARiG9j3VkYw1nWt80gIt16tKNbWph1obRc1imgOWtY5hA7VkGpk4oBpoD4TYzlEGFqi0SwlEfnwOMDvg6OqG5aAropyYgNZl2gHZNF3ZNVMrp5i4+al-noIFTYQCF-m7coFTQy1IDxUeSUpX56X0JlZAiyeeZoJRVabYgGH7bNTyVlByAYGgQ7lvQe1gRBBsgFWCNfj+yAACJBN0Osg0d1tW4+z5VjgVbE2QlXgRpIAACQVBDds2AACqMLuXrrtxg0jEcewRyBey+vvvpNPv2yAMceF9ydEG5BmXY1MWwyA8M2FLiUgKj5MY6nNiOc5e3x7TEJQ9XbYExpMCEMwZBC5hfZqWgCWqCgk4ycgnaMBPI6U9G1PxrTKYM2Y4ZAA).

The goal is to display a price difference in tooltip calculated as end value of selection - start value of selection. I calculate it as *price_diff* in my code, however the tooltip is displaying *NaN*, instead of the actual value.

What do I do wrong? Is it possible to set tooltip fields based on selection? I.e. display hover price when not selected and price difference when range is selected?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXCAxgewHYwIYQwUwCcQAaEKbHJUAN2wBsBXfAZyQG1QKZ8kQAmAAz8AjAFpBAFgkBWACqDBiRaRAAHQhBS9EIgGwBmAHSSZAXxJdKOgcPFSJehUpVkNWnfpFGA7Ocvk1nxCohLSgj7OyoKq7tpIIjIAnCb8FlY8wXZhEgAcUa7qmvG6evxG-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-DsSA+a8coZBxoQS4ZlgfCkQQ7bTjAaBqEBGFoKmqYsPgzZCRRTF8GAcBNrw3TKap6l8Yx1HILR9HhqeARYbhyBqGgeDNmQUYxvGibydgKBNuewEURgsZVpgiZ0EwOj3LkO6idWfC9h+xCudWagFkgqYMGpEZhcwx5IbZ7b2SAhCMD+eaiRgLCgR2HAgRA9A8Mx6jttgsXILGKkgDZoCQIFaBgDVIDyXw6YDjAAD62WfiA6aZtmDmjGQ2BAdNECjWNEKGWoklLeNk2qDNV7zcsi3LShLDjRt4YBLO9AoCV2LcLBRhnRdrQAARiG9j3VkYI3netC0gEt16tGN7Wpp1oaudGaArp5i4+al-noIFTYQCF-l7coFTRS1cVoAlqj4MlSPpfQmVkFjJ55mglFVltiAYQdc1PJWUHIBgaBDuW9D7WBEHsyAVa1pWE42AAIkE3TMyDx1C4Lj7PlWOBVh+fMdpQfAACQVBDX4-sgAAKozS5eLO3GDEAdbeBHIIrL4q++U3KwbIDGx4X1W6mRBuQZV1NTFimgOWIvIPFR5kGpk4oBpoD4TYjnOftZuKRyvBQyA0m0edSAwMV+BkBjmF9mpBMR6gk4ycgnaMKXI5EzDK6pym1kBCHNjg9Omb4DHeGC85RBhQ37kYHGzcgNZ4bhkAA)

One issue with your original code is that the selection doesn't snap to the nearest point. If you want to solve that too, you can read more about how to do so [here](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/2812).

```
{
  "width": "container",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2021-04-05T00:00", "price": 163.45},
      {"date": "2021-04-06T00:00", "price": 161.75},
      {"date": "2021-04-07T00:00", "price": 159.42},
      {"date": "2021-04-08T00:00", "price": 162.22},
      {"date": "2021-04-09T00:00", "price": 161.175},
      {"date": "2021-04-12T00:00", "price": 159.77},
      {"date": "2021-04-13T00:00", "price": 159.14},
      {"date": "2021-04-14T00:00", "price": 158.495},
      {"date": "2021-04-15T00:00", "price": 160.775},
      {"date": "2021-04-16T00:00", "price": 159.56},
      {"date": "2021-04-19T00:00", "price": 156.965},
      {"date": "2021-04-20T00:00", "price": 154.525},
      {"date": "2021-04-21T00:00", "price": 158.235},
      {"date": "2021-04-22T00:00", "price": 155.33},
      {"date": "2021-04-23T00:00", "price": 158.985},
      {"date": "2021-04-26T00:00", "price": 160.655},
      {"date": "2021-04-27T00:00", "price": 159.51},
      {"date": "2021-04-28T00:00", "price": 156.11},
      {"date": "2021-04-29T00:00", "price": 158.03},
      {"date": "2021-04-30T00:00", "price": 153.155},
      {"date": "2021-05-03T00:00", "price": 151.3},
      {"date": "2021-05-04T00:00", "price": 151.955}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "timeUnit": "yearmonthdatehoursminutes",
      "title": "",
      "scale": {"paddingInner": 1, "paddingOuter": 0}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "price",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "",
      "axis": {"formatType": "number"}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "area",
        "line": {"color": "red"},
        "color": {
          "x1": 1,
          "y1": 1,
          "x2": 1,
          "y2": 0,
          "gradient": "linear",
          "stops": [
            {"offset": 0, "color": "white"},
            {"offset": 1, "color": "red"}
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "point",
      "encoding": {
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"value": 0.8, "param": "hover", "empty": false},
          "value": 0
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "rule",
      "transform": [
        {"filter": {"param": "diff"}},
        {
          "window": [
            {"op": "first_value", "field": "price", "as": "first_price"},
            {"op": "last_value", "field": "price", "as": "last_price"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "calculate": "datum.last_price - datum.first_price",
          "as": "price_diff"
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"value": 0.2, "param": "hover", "empty": false},
          "value": 0
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {
            "field": "date",
            "type": "nominal",
            "formatType": "time",
            "title": "Date"
          },
          {
            "field": "price",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "format": "$.2f",
            "title": "Price"
          },
          {
            "field": "price_diff",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "title": "Price difference"
          }
        ]
      },
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "hover",
          "select": {
            "type": "point",
            "fields": ["price"],
            "nearest": true,
            "on": "mouseover",
            "clear": "mouseout",
            "encodings": ["x"]
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "diff",
          "select": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["x"]}
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```